# refresh when input in form is checked/unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit, checked, unchecked

i have a form, with some inputs, those inputs are my filters for my listing:

```
<form id="filter" method="get" action="" data-filter-form="true" data-count-ctrl="">
   <div class="filter-panel filter--property facet--property" data-filter-type="value-list" data-field-name="f">
   <div class="filter-panel--flyout" style="border:none;">
   <label class="filter-panel--title"><h3 class="rums">Type</h3></label></div>
      <div class="filter-panel--content">
      <ul class="filter-panel--option-list">
         <li class="filter-panel--option">
         <div class="option--container">
            <span class="filter-panel--checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="__f__283" name="__f__283" value="283">
            <span class="checkbox--state">&nbsp;</span></span>
            <label class="filter-panel--label" for="__f__283">Filter 283</label>
         </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is my function to submit the unchecked/checked inputs:

```
$('.filter-panel--option input').change(function () {
  if($(this).attr('checked') != "checked") {
     $('.' + $(this).attr('name')).prop("checked", $(this).prop('checked'));
     $('#filter').submit();
  } else {
     $('.' + $(this).removeAttr('checked'));
     $('#filter').submit();
  }
});
```

If the input (filter:283) is unchecked and i check it, the form is submitted, the site refreshes with a new url and my listing is refreshed:

```
develop.net/standard?p=1&o=1&n=15f=283
```

If the input is checked and i uncheck it, the form is not submitted, the site *does not* refresh and the url is the same:

```
develop.net/standard?p=1&o=1&n=15f=283
```

But i try to refresh the site, while unchecking a input, that the url is without the filter id:

```
develop.net/standard?p=1&o=1&n=15
```

Comment: `.prop("unchecked", $(this).prop('unchecked')` - `unchecked` does not exist. You un-check a checkbox, by setting the `checked` property to false.

Comment: It is unclear what you are even doing here, for example what the relation between the element you are handling this change event on, and the one you are setting the properties on, actually is … please provide a proper [mre] so we can see what is actually going on here.

Comment: I am sorry, i've edited my question! @04FS

Answer (score 2):

Try this, change this line:

```
if($(this).attr('checked') != "checked") {
```

to:

```
if($(this).is(':checked') ) {
```

-- edit

Also make sure you change the "change" event to click.

```
$('.filter-panel--option input').click(function () {
```

The change only occurs on input statements when the value changes, now the state changes and 'onchange' event does not read these changes.

Comment: I've changed it to, but it still not submit:
`if($(this).is(':checked') ) {`

Comment: thanks for your edit, but the result is the same, it doesn't read the filter changes